# dynamic add a linear layout to another

Tags: java, android

whats wrong with this code? it gave me this error:

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

```
    final LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    final LinearLayout ll2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
             CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
             TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                txt.setText("test!");
                ll2.addView(cb);
                ll2.addView(txt);
                ll.addView(ll2); //ERROR HERE
            }
        sc.addView(ll);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `ll.addView(ll2)` multiple times since it's in the loop. Move it outside the for loop:

```
final LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

final LinearLayout ll2 = new LinearLayout(this);
ll2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
    TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    txt.setText("test!");
    ll2.addView(cb);
    ll2.addView(txt);
}

ll.addView(ll2);
sc.addView(ll);
```